# How to use find_elements_by_tag_name in selenium for all loaded content on browser?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to use Selenium for my automation project.
In this case I realize `find_element_by_tag_name()` function returns the elements which display on browser so I basically used to `PAGE_DOWN` and run the function again.
The question is there any way to run `find_elements_by_tag_name` on whole loaded content in Selenium without scrolling down to page.

For example in my case I use this;

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
images = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

I don't want to send `PAGE_DOWN` because I already have whole page in the browser.
Note: `browser.page_source` is not solution.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: I believe the page might be loading the images dynamically when you scroll down. `find_element_by_tag_name` will identify all the elements with the given node in the entire page.

Comment: For that situation I manually scroll down and the page has loaded <img> elements more than 100 but it only shows e.g. 30-40.

Comment: have you checked in the dev tools if all 100 image nodes there on the page? With modern implementation you can show only n number of images and dynamically change their refs. So I would check in the dev tool, if your locator is returning 100 rather 30/40.

Comment: Yeah thanks for this detail  I figured out the problem. Although I scrolled down, the inspect elements doesn't show all of them.